# Doubt in Conditional inclusion

Tags: c++, c, language-agnostic

This is actually extracted from my module (Pre-processor in C)

***The conditional expression could contain any C operator except for the assignment operators,increment, and decrement operators.***

I am not sure if I am getting this statement or not since I tried using [this](http://ideone.com/r5Spc) and it worked.Also for other manipulation a probable work around would be to simply declare macro or function inside the conditional expression,[something like this to be precise](http://ideone.com/83Vm0).

Also I don't understand what is the rationale behind this rule. Could somebody explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what the phrase *conditional expression* refers to.
In this snippet

```
#if defined TEST
  int a = 0;
#endif
```

The conditional expression is the part being tested by the #if, meaning it is the `defined TEST` part.

The reason that assignment, increment and decrement are not allowed is because those operators want to change a variable, which is nonsensical in the context of the preprocessor.
The preprocessor works entirely based on textual substitution and evaluation of the resulting constant expressions.

If you have this code

```
#define X a++
#define Y 42

#if X == Y
#endif
```

Then in the test `#if X == Y`, first `X` and `Y` are replaced by their macro expansion (respectively `a++` and `42`), resulting in

```
#if a++ == 42
```

Next, `a` is replaced by its macro expansion. As there is no macro `a`, the replacement is defined to result in `0`:

```
#if 0++ == 42
```

Now there are no possible macro names left to expand, so the preprocessor tries to evaluate the condition. As there is an attempt to increment the constant `0`, this evaluation fails with an error.

Answer (score 4):

> The conditional expression could
>   contain any C operator except for the
>   assignment operators,increment, and
>   decrement operators.

This says, you cannot write these,

```
#if X = 4 //wrong

#if X++  //this too wrong

#if X-- //this too
```

---

EDIT:

I just read your comment on [Diego Sevilla's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554313/doubt-in-conditional-inclusion/4554353#4554353),

> Agreed but why something like this
>   (ideone.com/ahXDA) is not allowed ? –
>   Philando Gullible

This code actually equivalent to this which you write in the global scope,

```
//global code
int b=7; 
b++;  //ill-formed!
```

Which is not allowed in C (and C++). This however is allowed in C ONLY,

```
//legal in C Only
int b = 7;
int b; //well-formed!
```

Here the second definition is called **tentative definition**. C Standard says in $6.9.2/2,

> A declaration of an identifier for an
>   object that has file scope **without an
>   initializer**, and **without a
>   storage-class specifier** or with the
>   storage-class specifier static,
>   constitutes a *tentative definition*.If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

Which again implies, the following is not allowed,

```
//illegal in both C and C++
int b=7;
int b=8; //error
```

It's not a tentative definition anymore. It's redefinition, which is not allowed!

Comment: It's clear now since `#if` can only allow macros in its conditional expression, now as a macro cannot hold rvalue hence something like that doesn't makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph you put in bold refers to `#if` expressions, so you can use operators:

```
#if VARIABLE > 3
```

etc., not the code that is inside the macros you define.